# How to enable HTTPS in GWT's Jetty?

Tags: gwt, https, jetty

How can I enable HTTPS in Jetty, which comes with GWT?

Comment: Why do you need https on development server?

Comment: We have some secure features in our project which only are accessible via SSL. Thus, I need to test this feature as well.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a README-SSL.txt "hidden" in the gwt-dev.jar. You can find the latest version [on Github](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/README-SSL.txt).

In particular, add `-server :ssl` to the startup parameters of Jetty to use a default self-signed certificate for `localhost`.

Comment: any idea if this strategy still works? It's the only solution I can find, however if I run GWT with the -server :ssl args, I get 'Unable to load server class '''. This seems strange, all runs fine without the -server :ssl argument.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791758/run-gwt-with-https-enabled for expanded question regarding this issue.

Comment: This README-SSL.txt file really helped me with my problem trying to configure custom truststore to use for built-in server (Jetty) instead of the default one certificate for localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I think this can help some people there, I also use GWT and we were required to use HTTPS.

Basically we run gwt using maven, so the command is something like this to enable https.

```
gwt:debug -Dgwt.style=PRETTY -Dgwt.server=:ssl
```

And this is how my pom.xml section of the plugin looks like when running using jetty:run-war or jetty:run.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.19</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle-jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>${project.build.directory}/${warName}.war</webApp>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8080</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
                <port>8443</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
                <password>jetty6</password>
                <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>clean</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>genkey</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>genkey</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
        <dname>cn=localhost</dname>
        <keypass>jetty6</keypass>
        <storepass>jetty6</storepass>
        <alias>jetty6</alias>
        <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```