# Run gwt with https enabled?

Tags: gwt, ssl

I'm currently running a GWT site with no security, but need to make the switch over to HTTPS.

The working non-secure version runs with these arguments:

```
-port 8888 -startupUrl ui/index.jsp com.example.EntryPoint
```

I have read that simply adding -server :ssl will cause the site to be served with HTTPS enabled:

```
-port 8888 -startupUrl ui/index.jsp -server :ssl com.example.EntryPoint
```

However, with this I simply get

```
[ERROR] Unable to load server class ''
[ERROR] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$ArgHandlerServer.setString(DevMode.java:108)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ArgHandlerString.handle(ArgHandlerString.java:26)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ToolBase.processArgs(ToolBase.java:225)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.ArgProcessorBase.processArgs(ArgProcessorBase.java:29)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:281)
[ERROR] Google Web Toolkit 2.1.0
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if that method doesn't work any more?
Is anyone successfully running this command or gwt with SSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to use the embedded jetty server, SSL support was added in [r9628](http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1324801). You are using GWT 2.1, so either try to update to a more recent version (at least GWT 2.3), or use an external SSL-preconfigured server for your application (option `-noserver`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, have you successfully run a later version with ssl using this command out of curiosity?

Comment: @Erix nope, never used SSL in DevMode.

Comment: I am trying to run GWT on an SSL-enabled Spring Boot server, but no luck. Can you guys please help me?

I get the following error:

    The page at (ip):8888 says: Couldn't load (app) from Super Dev Mode server 
    at http://(ip):9876. Please make sure this server is ready. Do you want to try 
    again?